# C# String.Format Characters

Tags: c#

Just starting to muddle my way through C# and I have a question which maybe really simple (Once somebody explains it to me).

I have a text box asking for the users National Insurance Number (This is program doesn't do anything it's just me trying to figure out the formatting sequences) - But I'm pulling my hair out trying to work out how to display this back to the label.

at the moment I have the following

```
string result = String.Format("Thank you, {0}"+
            " for your business. You NI # is {1:???}",
             nameTextBox.Text,
             socialTextBox.Text);

        resultLabel.Text = result;
```

I don't know what to replace the ? with..  Any help would be really appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: How does NI looks?I mean what is the pattern?

Comment: Why do you need the semicolon? Do you need your output has a specific format? Could you please state more clearly what's the expected format ? Thanks

Comment: Your parameter is just a string and the only formatting you can do with strings is alignment and spacing (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I was looking for something like BN-201285-T (I hope this sheds a bit more light on it?)

Comment: What is your expected input? In general you would need to identify the parts of your input and reassemble them in your desired format. This can often be done by using a regular expession. Formatting sequences in general only help you for numbers and date times - all other data types can just be output as is (with additional padding).

Comment: I was hoping if the user entered BN201285T it would output BN-201285-T - To be honest I haven't gotten as far as regular expressions, only the very basics of the String.Format, so I might need to put this to one side and carry on learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was looking for something like BN-201285-T

You could make your own function that formats the string to the desired format :

```
private string CustomFormat(string input) {
    return string.Format("BN-{0}-T", input);
}
```

Then pass the formated string to the **string.Format** call :

```
string result = String.Format("Thank you, {0}" +
            " for your business. You NI # is {1}",
             nameTextBox.Text,
             CustomFormat(socialTextBox.Text));

resultLabel.Text = result;
```